# Invoke C program with argv[0] as NULL

Tags: c, argv

The following is from a book on secure C coding:

> Vulnerabilities can occur when inadequate space is allocated to copy a
> program input such as a command-line argument. Although argv[0]
> contains the program name by convention, an attacker can control the
> contents of argv[0] to cause a vulnerability in the following program
> by providing a string with more than 128 bytes. Furthermore, an
> attacker can invoke this program with argv[0] set to NULL:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   /* ... */
   char prog_name[128];
   strcpy(prog_name, argv[0]);
   /* ... */
}
```

I want to ask how will the attacker invoke the program with `argv[0]` set to `NULL`, if `argv[0]` is the program name ?

Comment: Read the passage again: "`argv[0]` contains the program name **by convention**".  The attacker does not have to follow that convention.

Comment: This is really only an issue on suid-programs. If the attacker can trick your program into doing shenanigans by calling it with `argv[0]==NULL`, he has all the necessary permissions to the same shenanigans directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the a function like `execlp()` to start the program, instead of running the program from a shell. All the `exec` functions require the caller to provide the `argv` elements explicitly, and they can easily violate the convention.

```
execlp("program_name", (char *)NULL);
```

Note that there are actually some uses for this ability. Not specifically  `argv[0] == NULL`, but the option to make `argv[0]` different from the program name. There's another convention that login shells are run with `-` as the first character of `argv[0]` (because the traditional login process doesn't provide a way to pass parameters to the shell).